# Preventing Next.js from generating certain path files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, koa

I'm currently building an e-commerce (Shopify, BigCommerce, etc.) extension using Node.js, Koa, React, and Next.js.

As part of the codebase, I have URL methods that must only be executed on the server-side.  There should be no page generated for the URL.  However, Next.js always requires a page to be generated.

Is there a way to only have Next.js simply invoke the URL method rather than generate a page?  For example, `/app/auth` should not generate a page, but instead execute server code.  However, `/app/dashboard` should generate a page.

I'm aware of using `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` as a way to prevent this behavior.  However, I found that it's quite wonky since it also needs client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, Next.js always requires a page to be generated

No, That's not true, you can use [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) an decide if a route should or should not render a page.

A simple example with express.js:
**rendere a page** :

```
  server.get('/my-page', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/mypage', {...req.params, ...req.query})
  })
```

**An api endpoint** :

```
server.post("/my-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
     res.json({});
});
```

Note that  to run the custom server you'll need to update the scripts in package.json with something like this :

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node server.js",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
```

If you are using Koa.js there is an official example for custom server with koa [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-koa)

Comment: Apparently, I made the "didn't read the documentation properly" error.  I had packages.json to use the ```next``` command line to launch the server.  Thank you for clarifying.